# Confessing for a crime which has not been committed

Tags: criminal-law

A person confessed to a lawyer over phone for a blackmailing (his lover)crime which he didn't commit. Will he able to file a complaint against that person only with his confession? But such crime has not occured and the lawyer doesn't know any other details

Comment: Please add a Jurasdiction.

Comment: Nothing constitutional here... Civil or criminal?

Comment: Criminal related

Comment: Will _who_ be able to file a complaint?  The lawyer, the confessor, the confessor's lover, or someone else?

Comment: Whether the lawyer be able to file a complaint?

Comment: Is Bob being accused of that blackmail? Is this even his lawyer? Why would the lawyer want to file a complaint?

Answer (score 2):

The person who is blackmailed can file a criminal complaint. A random person who thinks there was a crime cannot. A person's lawyer especially cannot even anonymously tip off the police about bad past act of the client.